# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).smartresize is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am using gentelella dashboard theme for my website and I am getting this error while loading the page.

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).smartresize is not a function

Following is my code:

```
$(window).smartresize(function(){a()}),a()
```

Comment: what is the question? the error is pretty clear, that function does not exist. Are you sure you imported the script which includes that function?

Comment: Hi, you need to load a library on your page before you can use `smartresize` like that.

Comment: I have included the library at the bottom.

Comment: Put it at the top, it loads and executes from top to bottom.

Comment: Keeping custom.min.js gives me another error.

Comment: which library you are using , please add a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `jQuery` and your library before calling `$(...).smartresize`:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="smartresize.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).smartresize(function(){a()}),a()
</script>
```

or call it once the page load event is triggered if you add the scripts at the end of your `body`:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    $(window).smartresize(function(){a()}),a()
  }, false);
</script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="smartresize.js"></script>
```